# Rotation keyframes not recorded in python

Tags: python

```
for n in range(5):
size = n + 1
print(n)
print(size)
#ADD IT ALL TO PARENT EMPTY OBJECT
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='SPHERE', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, n + 1), scale=(1, 1, 1))
empty_obj = context.object

add_circle(size,empty_obj)
add_text(n,empty_obj)

#add keyframes for empty object rotation

#start settings first frame here
scene.frame_set(scene.frame_start)
current_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
empty_obj.rotation_euler[2] = 0.0
#empty_obj.keyframe_insert("rotation_euler",current_frame)
empty_obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler",frame=current_frame)

#settings middle frame here
empty_obj.rotation_euler[2] = 6.0

# Set keyframe for middle frame.
scene.frame_set(scene.frame_start + (scene.frame_end - scene.frame_start) // 2)
current_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
empty_obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler",frame=current_frame)

#settings last frame here
empty_obj.rotation_euler[2] = 0.0
# Set keyframe for last frame.
scene.frame_set(scene.frame_end)
current_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
#empty_obj.keyframe_insert("rotation_euler",current_frame)
empty_obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler",frame=current_frame)
```

I'm trying to record the rotation of my empty object, and the keyframes are added, but the value is not changed (empty_obj.rotation_euler[2] = 6.0). I can't seem to find the documentation in the api either for this method obj.keyframe_insert(). What am I missing?

Comment: frame_set will change the value. Try the order frame_set => set the value you want => keyframe_insert.

Comment: Could you fix the cut'n'paste of your code?  It seems to have lost all indentation, and you're using the variable scene without having set it anywhere, among others. Is it `bpy.context.scene` perhaps?

Comment: the scene is set just above this code block. I know the indentation... I don't know how to set it right, tab does not work.

Comment: @scurest thanks, the order was indeed the reason! My bad, sloppiness by working to fast without proper re-reading.

Comment: @hdries Glad it worked. You also don't need to do _both_ frame_set and pass the frame to [keyframe_insert](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert). Either one or other will work (just passing the frame and not doing frame_set would be easier I think).